# canvas spiral rise effect with turning points

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, spiral

There is a spiral rise effect as showed bellow: 
[image: spiral rise effect]
A demo can be found here: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/dynamic-data.html

In the bottom of the demo page, an algorithm is used to implement this effect. But I can not figure out how does it work.

```
var t = theta + 2 * Math.PI * i / n;
var x = (R + r) * Math.cos(t) + p * Math.cos((R + r) * t / r);
var y = (R + r) * Math.sin(t) + p * Math.sin((R + r) * t / r);
```

What does R, r and p means? And how to understand the formula above? Can someone explain detail for me? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recognize that code draws [epicycloid curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicycloid) (+ it's phase `theta` permanently changes to provide moving effect).

You can refer to **R** as radius of inner (here bigger) circle, **p** and **r** (equal values here) as radius of outer (here smaller) circle. Here **r** looks like radius of coil of toroidal spring.

The first summands correspond to the center of outer circle, the second ones - to the second-order rotation about outer circle center.

Play with these values and observe effects

Note that if you change **p** to make it not equal to **r**, you'll get [epitrochoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitrochoid) curve (more general kind of epicycloid)